# Why does the outcome change when the variable is declared within the while loop?

Tags: javascript

I have two simple functions here. In the `loop` function I have defined facky as one at the top of the function. Two things I do not understand:

1. The answer to `console.log(loop(5))` is 120 when `facky` is defined at the top of `loop`
2. When I move `var facky = 1;` within the while loop, the answer is 2. I understand why this is two. What I don't understand is why the behavior is different when the variable is outside?

```js
function loop(size) {

  while (size > 1) {
    var facky = 1;
    facky = facky * size;
    size = size - 1;

  }
  clunk(facky);
}


function clunk(times) {
  var num = times;

  while (num > 0) {
    console.log("clunk");
    num = num - 1;
  }
}

loop(5);
```

Comment: **var** is declared globally, replace `var` with `let`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: @AhsanKhan `var` is function scoped when declared inside of a function. Not globally.

Comment: The difference is redeclaring facky each iteration of the loop. By doing that it is the same as doing `var facky = 1 * size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop, whenever the loop iterates, `facky` is reset to 1, so it will only print twice because the last iteration of the while loop multiplies `facky` by 2.

When you move the declaration outside of the while loop, `facky` does not reset after every iteration and takes on the value of `5!`, or `120` after the final iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare a variable inside a loop. Try this instead:

```
function loop(size) {
  
  var facky = 1;

  while (size > 1) {
    facky = facky * size;
    size = size - 1;
  }

  clunk(facky);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter where you declare the `var facky`, it's always function-scoped.

What matters is whether you reset `facky = 1` in every iteration of your loop, or whether you only initialise it once before the loop.